# Want to get rid of thin line on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap navbar which creates a thin line when I expand it by clicking the mobile button.  I can't figure out what part of the CSS I have to change to get rid of it.  Can anyone help?
[image]

Here is a [link](http://www.travterrell.com/sampleblog) to my site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the border-bottom from bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572765/how-to-remove-the-border-bottom-from-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `box-shadow` property on `#myNavbar`. The following rule will fix it.

```
#myNavbar {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Boom!  Thank you sir!